# Vue Error when creating and hosting a website: This dependency was not found-

Tags: vue.js, web-frontend

I’m learning Vue.js for Front-End and the course currently I’m studying is about creating a commercial website. Since I have created a ‘404 Not Found Page’ for the demo commercial website, I shall run ‘npm run serve’ in the terminal of code editor, in order to visit and monitor the localhost website.
I received an error message says that:

ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors
This dependency was not found:

- vue/types/umd in ./src/router/index.js
  To install it, you can run: npm install --save vue/types/umd

I have tried to run npm install --save vue/types/umd as VS code suggested. I received the following error message:

npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "vue\types\umd" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\wangg\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-12-22T23_27_39_562Z-debug.log

Could anyone help, please?

Answer (score 8):

I just saw this error and came across this post. In my case I think my IDE had automatically added an `import` for `vue/types/umd` as I was experimenting with the `nextTick` function. It may have been a sloppy keyboard combo in my part, I'm not sure.

Removing that rogue import line solved the problem for me.

(Assume you've solved this by now, adding my answer for posterity.)